# Can custom exception thrown from Webclient onStatus method?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, webclient

I am trying to throw a custom exception from Web client onstatus method after checking the Httpstatus.When i tried capturing the thrown exception it was captured as a normal Exception but not the custom exception.

```
public String getResponse(String request){ 
 try{
   randomService.getResponse(request);
    }catch(AuthException e){
     throw new AuthException(e.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception e){
     throw new InternalServerError(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public String returnResponse(String request){
  return webclient.post()
           .uri("")
           .header("","")
           .body(BodyInserters.formatValue(requestMessage))
           .retrieve()
           .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientRes -> {
                if(401){
                    return Mono.error(new AuthException("traceid)));
                       }
     }).bodyToMono(String.class).block();
}
```

Not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Show us the logs

Comment: I'm guessing the code provided above is more pseudo code? Or is it the actually code in your application?

Comment: It's the actual code

Comment: the code above does not compile `if(401){ }`  is not valid java code